# When are filtered colimits of (trivial) cofibrations still (trivial) cofibrations?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a

> locally finitely presentable model category, cofibrantly generated by
> two sets $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{J}$ of cofibrations and trivial
> cofibrations with presentable domain and codomain.

I know that weak equivalences and fibrations are stable by filtered colimits.

> 1. What can be said about cofibrations and trivial cofibrations?
> 2. Is there a class of good examples in which this is known to be
>    true?
> 3. Are there additional axioms that can be imposed that ensure this?

Comment: The best account I am aware of is in Rosicky's "On combinatorial model categories".

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti I have seen that paper, but I haven't found anything I could use about my question. I'll try to take another look. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to assume $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{J}$ have _finitely_ presentable domain and codomain?

Comment: @ZhenLin  Yes. I mean to assume that hom(A, -) preserves with filtered colimits

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If both cofibrations and weak equivalences are stable under filtered colimits, then so are trivial cofibrations. This happens for instance if $\mathcal{M}$ is a presheaf category on an elegant Reedy category (such as $\Delta$)  with cofibrations the monomorphisms, whatever the weak equivalences are (see Cor. 3.4.41 & (the proof of) Prop. 8.2.9 [here](https://smf.emath.fr/publications/les-prefaisceaux-comme-modeles-des-types-dhomotopie)). This is also true for cochain complexes in a Grothendieck abelian category (with cofibrations as monomorphisms and quasi-isomorphisms as weak equivalences). Similarly, if you consider simplicial sheaves on a site. More generally, if you can define cofibrations and weak equivalences using functors which commute with filtered colimits (e.g. suitable kernels to detect monomorphisms in a topos, cohomology sheaves or sheaves of homotopy groups to detect weak equivalences), you have a good chance of survival. This kind of properties is easily seen to be preserved under left Bousfield localizations.

Comment: so it seems that this property is quite common in examples arising in nature. thank you for the overview.